# Symfony2 Entity Field Type current choices

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I'm trying to create an entity field type in form. Here is the code:

```
$extraSpecsRepository = $this -> getDoctrine() 
                              -> getRepository('LabsCatalogBundle:Specs'); 
$availQuery = $extraSpecsRepository->createQueryBuilder('sel')
                ->where("sel.cat = '0'")
                ->getQuery();
$available = $availQuery->getResult();


$extraSpecsRepository = $this -> getDoctrine() 
                              -> getRepository('LabsCatalogBundle:ProductExtraspecs'); 
$selQuery = $extraSpecsRepository->createQueryBuilder('sel')
                  ->join('sel.specs', 'specs')
                  ->where("specs.cat = '0' AND sel.regmatid = $id")
                  ->getQuery();
$selected = $selQuery->getResult();



$form = $this ->createFormBuilder($product)
                ->add('extraspecs', 'entity', array(
                                'class' => 'LabsCatalogBundle:Specs',
                                'choices' => $typeavailable,
                                'data' => $selected,
                                'property' => 'specid',
                                'multiple' => false,
                            ))
                ->getForm();
```

And this is the `var_dump` from both `$selected` and `$typeavailable` variables`:

```
$typeavailable:    
array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'specid' => int 20
          'desc' => string 'Primary Antibodies' (length=18)
          'cat' => int 0
          'type' => int 1
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'specid' => int 21
          'desc' => string 'Secondary Antibodies' (length=20)
          'cat' => int 0
          'type' => int 2
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'specid' => int 22
          'desc' => string 'Fluorescent-Labeled Antibodies' (length=30)
          'cat' => int 0
          'type' => int 5
      3 => &
        array (size=4)
          'specid' => int 27
          'desc' => string 'Related Antibodies' (length=18)
          'cat' => int 0
          'type' => int 7

$selected:
    array (size=1)
      0 => &
        array (size=4)
          'regmatid' => int 1600
          'specid' => int 21
          'attrib' => null
          'value' => null
```

Do you see anything wrong?
Because it is generating the droplist but not choosing the 'selected' value.

Comment: I might be wrong but I'm pretty sure that the array item you put in the 'data' attribute needs to match exactly to one of the items in the choices. It looks like yours doesn't do this, only sharing one property.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: Fairly sure, you could test it by hardcoding your $selected to array ('specid' => 27, 'desc' => 'Related Antibodies', 'cat' => 0, 'type' => 7) and see if that shows up selected? And then changing it slightly and see if it is no longer selected?

Comment: I was asking that because I've made exactly the same test but it dind't work... still no selection... And I don't know waht to do more..

Comment: Can you show the code were you define `$typeavailable` and `$selected`.

Comment: Sure... I've edited the question to include the code.. Thank you

Comment: Last question: Does the entity `ProductExtraspecs` have a one to one relationship to the `Specs` entity? If not what kind of relationship do they have.

Comment: No... its manyToOne... ProductExtraspecs can have several specs, but specs are unique. This ProductsExtraspecs is an intermediate table bettwen Product and Specs where every row has one Product ID and one Specs ID but every product can have several Specs ID.. 
Do you need more information?

Comment: So `$selected->getSpecs();` would return more then 1 object?

Comment: It could return more then 1 object... but since I make a filter for only "cat=0" it will give only 1... but yes... it could return more (of diferent cat)..

Comment: Added an answer that explains it a bit and suggest things you could do. Tell me if that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects given to the `'choices'` index (`$typeavailable`) should be of the same class as the SINGLE object given to `'data'`. At the moment you are giving back an `array` holding the wrong object. Why a single object? Because your form supports only 1 selected item (`'multiple' => false,`).

Use this to fix the problem:

```
$result = $selQuery->getSingleResult()->getSpecs();
$selected = $result[0];
```

This piece of code should give you the Specs object you want selected.

If your select query also returns more then 1 object you might want to redo something in your relationships or query. If you don't want to do that you can still use the following:

```
$results = $selQuery->getResult();
$result = $results[0]->getSpecs();
$selected = $result[0];
```

Comment: `getSpecs()[0]` is valid for PHP 5.5, nope? Or PHP 5.4 is ok?

Comment: Nop... still not working... 
Went to check the generated HTML  and found that the values in the options are 0,1,2,3 instead of 20,21,22,27 that are the values that should be in the $available choices... is this ok?

Comment: No it's not. The value should be the `id` of the object. What does `$selected->getId()` return?

Comment: $selected ->getSpecid() gives a value between 20 and 22 or 27 depending on the product.. its ok.. and actually now everything is working perfectly... it is selecting.. but the value in the options are still 0,1,2 and 3.. What I think its happening is that it compares the objects, not the ids...
I just hope to not have problems on saving selected information to the database... 
Anyway thank you very much for everything... I was almost giving up from Symfony...